# Need to write a regex to extract path for first 5 slashes or up to a number for Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

Hi I need to write a regex to extract path from the first 5 slashes from the path or up to a number
Example:

```
https://example.com/first/second/third/fourth/fifth/sixth 
https://example.com/first-1/second-1/third-1/
https://example.com/first-1/second-1/third-1
https://example.com/first/12345
```

Result:

```
/first/second/third/fourth/fifth
/first-1/second-1/third-1
/first-1/second-1/third-1
/first
```

I am able to strip off the domain by using the regex

```
http(s)*\:\/\/([^\/]+)\/(?<uri>[^\?\s]+)
```

However, I am unable to get the first 5 or up to a numeric value is reached.

Answer (score 1):

This [ugliness](https://regex101.com/r/VJrCM1/3) will do what you want (though you may need to strip the ending `/`, if you don't want it (note - it's skipping everything in the URL *prior to* the path):

```
\/\/[^\/]+(?<pathnoendingnumbers>\/[a-zA-Z-_][-_\w]+(\/[a-zA-Z-_][-_\w]+(\/[a-zA-Z-_][-_\w]+(\/[a-zA-Z-_][-_\w]+(\/[a-zA-Z-_][-_\w]+)?)?)?)?)[\/\d$]?
```

It's an 88-step match, which may be improvable - but it's pretty efficient as is

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
https?:\/\/[^\/]+(?<uri>(?:\/[^\/\s]*[^\d\/\s][^\/\s]*){1,5})
```

JavaScript example:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://example.com/first/second/third/fourth/fifth/sixth', 
  'https://example.com/first-1/second-1/third-1/',
  'https://example.com/first-1/second-1/third-1',
  'https://example.com/first/12345',
];

const rx = /https?:\/\/[^\/]+((?:\/[^\/\s]*[^\d\/\s][^\/\s]*){1,5})/;

for (const u of urls) {
  const m = u.match(rx);
  if (m) console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Crucially, the part of the pattern which matches the value between forward slashes,

`[^\/\s]*[^\d\/\s][^\/\s]*`

will not match if there are only digits in between the slashes, because `[^\d\/\s]` will only match a character that is not a digit, forward slash or whitespace character.

If you know there is no whitespace in the urls, then all the `\s` can be removed.